# Predictive Search - wordpress shopkeeper theme (woocommerce - php file)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the shopkeeper wordpress theme and have the predictive search enabled.
I wanted to override the way the products were shown in the shop and category pages so i edited the woocommerce archive-product.php file (created folder in child theme and edited the file there). But the products in the predictive search won't show the same way as they are shown in the shop page.
Which file should i edit so that the predictive search will show the products the same way as the shop page?

Comment: Instead of copying the templates from woocommerceplugin, you need to make it from your parent theme woocommerce folder instead…

Comment: Yes, i know. That's exactly what i did. Every change i make is working right. The thing is, i don't know which file to edit so that i can make the products in the predictive search look the same as the shop page. I haven't worked with a theme that shows the products this way in the predictive search so i don't know where is this file/template located.

Comment: Predictive search is a custom feature of your commercial theme as  it doesn't exist by default in Woocommerce…